# Is it safe and portable to cast pointer to any type to char pointer for arithmetic?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Considering the following snippet, and for both C and C++ languages, is:

```
int t[2] = { 0, 1 };
*( (int *)( (char *)t + sizeof(int) ) ) = 2;
```

always equivalent to:

```
int t[2] = { 0, 1 };
t[1] = 2;
```

?

It might sound weird but I imagined some reasons why it could be false on some platforms:

1. `char` pointer increment could go in a reverse way than `int` pointer, unless it is not authorized by  the standard (in this case I would like to find where the standards states so)
2. the cast from `int *` to `char *` could be unsafe because there is not guaranty that their size are the same (and in this case, could it work with an intermediate cast to `void *`?), and because the standard does not guaranty that casting to `char *` and then to a pointer to any type is safe

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Notably C++ has stricter rules on pointer arithmetic and object lifetime so the answer could differ for the two language. You should specify which language you are actually asking about.

Comment: Not sure strict-aliasing allows to write though the `char*`

Comment: For (1) even if it is not explicitly stated in the standard, it is pretty well implied by the array semantics and other provisions of pointer arithmetics, that arrays grow upwards.

Comment: @Jarod42 `char` is excluded from type aliasing rules for both read and write. However other rules could interfere. Some types have unspecified representation so writing through `char*` is unspecified behavior. For `int` I'm not sure what other rules could come into play.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I agree but is it guaranteed?

Comment: @FlashMcQueen Yes. If this isn't allowed it isn't because arrays of different types grow in different directions.

Comment: Please choose one language. The question is interesting, but becomes a bit broad if you include both languages

Comment: @klutt I am eager to learn about both languages in this case :-)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux does the standard forbid arrays of different types to grow in different directions?

Comment: @FlashMcQueen It guaranties that the address of any element in any array compares `<` to the address of any other element in that same array if the former element's index is smaller than the later element's index.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I guess the term "address" is not used explicitly, but it is definitely true that `(uintptr_t)(void*)(&a[0]) < (uintptr_t)(void*)(&a[1])` for any array type `a`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Or just `&a[0] < &a[1]`. This is one of the few cases pointers can be compared. Instead of address I should have said "pointers to".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Added the cast to `void*` to defend against "< might e defined differently for different pointer types"

Comment: @EugeneSh. Makes sense, sounds like a question someone would propose.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Well still leaves the space for "the cast to void* is defined differently for different pointer types" though

Comment: @FlashMcQueen " I am eager to learn about both languages in this case" may be true, yet now you need a subject expect in 2 languages. You are then more likely to get a _OK_  2 language answer than a 1 _expert_ level answer for one. Better to post a 2nd question if the first does not satisfy.

Comment: You couldn't implement `memcpy`, `malloc`, etc. which all work with void pointers if pointer arithmetic went in different directions depending on the type.

Comment: @nwellnhof True, one cannot implement `memcpy, malloc` in C "if pointer arithmetic went in different directions depending on the type. ", but the Std C lib implementation is not limited to C.  OP's code is limited to C /(C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe and portable to cast pointer to any type to char pointer for arithmetic?

*Any* type --> No.

(Non-null) function pointers cast to `char *` is UB and then math applied is UB.

A `char *` may even be too small to encode a function pointer.

Comment: Maybe add "yes" - for any object type?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Maybe for object types, yet OP is asking a broad question about any type and in 2 languages.  OP does not provide the overall goal, so with general questions, general answers.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Hmmm, is an array of arbitrary function pointers valid strictly conforming C code then?  Or only function pointers that are all of the exact same type?

Comment: @AndrewHenle In the "array of arbitrary function pointers" the address of the array elements are a pointer to a function pointer, so we are back to _object_ pointer math.  Note - function pointers are all the same size - though may differ from some/all _object_ pointers.